# How can I make my hard drive and SSD the same as when i purchased them?

Tags: windows, ssd, reset

I have A gaming computer with a 2TB Hard drive and 250 gb SSD. lately i feel games i have installed and reinstalled over and over, and then other programs ive deleted are still remaining on the drives, taking up space, and complicating things. I'd like to not have to purchase new drives, but i also dont want ANY of the data on the ones i own, including the OS. How can i do this without ruining the drives, or leaving anything on them?

Comment: err...by downloading a linux live image, putting it onto a USB pendrive, and then running `dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/sdX`, where `X` is your HDD and formatting your SSD, then use the removal tool by its manufacturer?

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow for me but it sounds like you want to format your drive? That would delete all the data on them. Not necessarily in a secure way, someone might restore it later on if you don't take some precautions. Just deleting the existing partitions during Windows setup is probably going to be sufficient.